# removing chapter title in one of my chapters?

Tags: formatting, chapters, xepersian

I have written my thesis in LaTeX (`xepesian`) and I have customized my chapters title as follows,

```
‎\makeatletter‎
‎\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height‎ .‎5ex \hfill \kern \z@}‎
‎\def\position{\centering}‎
%% ‎Note the difference between the commands the one is‎ 
%% ‎make and the other one is makes‎
‎\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%‎
  ‎\vspace*{10\p@}%‎
  ‎{\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font‎
        ‎{\Huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}%\Huge \scshape  \thechapter‎ }
        ‎\par\nobreak‎
        ‎\vspace*{140\p@}%‎
        ‎\interlinepenalty\@M‎
        ‎\thickhrule‎
        ‎\par\nobreak‎
        ‎\vspace*{2\p@}%‎
        ‎{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}‎
        ‎\par\nobreak‎
        ‎\vspace*{2\p@}%‎
        ‎\thickhrule‎
    ‎\vskip 40\p@‎
    ‎\vskip 100\p@‎
  }
}
```

Now I want to remove this title in the one of my chapters( references (unnumbered) chapter). How I can do that??

My main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx} % inserting images‎
‎\usepackage{hyperref} % PDF links‎
‎\usepackage{setspace} % for switching between double/single space in document‎
‎\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}‎
‎%\usepackage{amsmath}‎
‎\usepackage{multirow}‎
‎\usepackage{float}‎
‎\usepackage{pdfpages}‎
‎\usepackage{cite}‎
‎\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}‎
‎\usepackage{subfigure}‎
‎%\usepackage{subcaption}‎
‎\usepackage{float}‎
‎\usepackage{caption}‎
‎\usepackage{enumerate}‎
‎\usepackage{cite}‎
‎\usepackage{fancyhdr} % package for changing Headings style‎
% ‎setting the margins of page‎
‎%\usepackage[top=3cm,right=4cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm]{geometry}‎                 
‎\usepackage[top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=4cm]{geometry1}‎              
‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎
‎\usepackage{xcolor}% sets colour‎
‎\usepackage{sectsty}% sets colour‎
‎\usepackage{float}‎
‎\usepackage{fixltx2e}%for sub and superscript in text‎
‎\newcommand{\zir}{\LTRfootnote}‎
‎\newcommand{\sub}{\textsubscript}‎
‎%\newcommand{\super}{\textsuperscript}‎
‎\newcommand{\marja}{\textcolor{blue}}‎
‎\newcommand{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}‎
‎\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}  % sets numbering in contents‎
‎\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% sets numbering in subsubsection‎
‎%\chapterfont{\color{blue}} % sets colour of chapters‎
‎%\sectionfont{\color{red}} % sets colour of sections‎
‎%\subsectionfont{\color{brown}}‎
‎%\DefaultMathsDigits‎
‎\hypersetup{%‎
‎colorlinks=true,% hyperlinks will be coloured‎
‎linkcolor=blue,% hyperlink text will be blue‎
 ‎citecolor=red,% color of links to bibliography‎
}
% ‎tell tex engine address of folder containing your pictures‎
‎\graphicspath{{pics/}}‎
% ‎commands to print the page number in header‎
‎\cfoot{}‎
‎\lhead{\thepage}‎
% ‎commands related to XePersian package‎
‎\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{XB Niloofar}‎
‎\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}%Zar}‎
‎\setdigitfont{XB Niloofar}%Times New Roman}‎
‎%\setlatintextfont{LinLibertine}‎
‎\makeatletter‎ 
‎\def\@myabjad#1{\ifcase#1\or‎ أ‎‍\or‎ ب‎\or‎ ج‎\or‎ د‎\or‎ ه‎\or‎ و‎\or‎
ز‎\or‎ ح‎\or‎ ط‎\or‎ ی‎\or‎ ک‎\or‎ ل‎\or‎ م‎\or‎ ن‎\or‎ س‎\or‎ ع‎\or‎ ف‎\or‎ ص‎\or‎ ق\orر‎\or‎
ش‎\or‎ ت‎\or‎ ث‎\or‎ خ‎\or‎ ذ‎\or‎ ض‎\or‎ ظ‎\or‎ غ‎\or‎ ء‎\or \else\@ctrerr\fi}‎
‎\def\myabjad#1{\expandafter\@myabjad\csname c@#1\endcsname}‎
‎\makeatother‎
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
‎\makeatletter‎
‎\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height‎ .‎5ex \hfill \kern \z@}‎
‎\def\position{\centering}‎
%% ‎Note the difference between the commands the one is‎ 
%% ‎make and the other one is makes‎
‎\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%‎
  ‎\vspace*{10\p@}%‎
  ‎{\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font‎
        ‎{\Huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}%\Huge \scshape  \thechapter‎ }
        ‎\par\nobreak‎
        ‎\vspace*{140\p@}%‎
        ‎\interlinepenalty\@M‎
        ‎\thickhrule‎
        ‎\par\nobreak‎
        ‎\vspace*{2\p@}%‎
        ‎{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}‎
        ‎\par\nobreak‎
        ‎\vspace*{2\p@}%‎
        ‎\thickhrule‎
    ‎\vskip 40\p@‎
    ‎\vskip 100\p@‎
  }}
%% ‎The following commands must be used if we want to change the Form of the title of tableofcontent‎ ,...
‎%\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%‎
 % ‎\vspace*{10\p@}%‎
  ‎%{\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font‎
   %     ‎{\Huge \scshape \vphantom{\thechapter}}‎
    %    ‎\par\nobreak‎
     %   ‎\vspace*{10\p@}%‎
      %  ‎\interlinepenalty\@M‎
       % ‎\thickhrule‎
%        ‎\par\nobreak‎
 %       ‎\vspace*{2\p@}%‎
  %      ‎{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}‎
 %       ‎\par\nobreak‎
  %      ‎\vspace*{2\p@}%‎
   %     ‎\thickhrule‎
   % ‎\vskip 100\p@‎
  %}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
‎\renewcommand{\bibname}{مراجع}‎
‎%\renewcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{red}}‎
‎\input{jeld_info}‎ 
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\include{cover_fa}‎
‎\input{besmellah}‎ 
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎
‎\include{ezharnameh}‎
‎\include{taeid}‎ 
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎  
‎%\pagenumbering{Alph}‎
  ‎\include{setayesh}‎ 
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎  
‎\pagenumbering{myabjad}‎  
‎\include{taghdim}‎ 
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎    
‎\include{sepas}‎
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎    
‎%\pagenumbering{harfi}‎ 
‎\include{abstract_fa}‎         
‎\tableofcontents‎
% ‎insert each of your chapters with a \include{filename} command as below‎
‎\doublespacing‎
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎
‎\include{chap1}‎
‎\singlespacing‎
‎\baselineskip 27pt‎
‎\include{references}‎
‎\end{document}‎
```

and the references is :

```
\chapter*{مراجع}%\markboth{مراجع}{مراجع}‎
‎\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{مراجع}‎
‎%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}‎
‎%\pagenumbering{arabic}‎
‎\thispagestyle{empty}‎
‎‎\begin{thebibliography}{99} \small‎
‎\begin{latin}‎
‎\bibitem{Janssen}‎
‎P‎. ‎J‎. ‎C‎. ‎Janssen and C‎ .‎R‎ . ‎Acad‎. ‎Sci‎. ‎Paris \textbf{67}‎, ‎494 (1868)‎.
‎\bibitem{Lockyer}‎
‎J‎. ‎N‎. ‎Lockyer and C‎. ‎R‎. ‎Acad‎. ‎Sci‎. ‎Paris \textbf{67}‎, ‎836 (1868)‎.
‎\bibitem{Ramsay}‎
‎W‎. ‎Ramsay‎, ‎Nature (London) \textbf{51}‎, ‎512 (1895); \textbf{52}‎, ‎7 (1895)‎.
\end{latin}‎
‎\end{thebibliography}‎
```

(SORRY FOR LONG AND LORGE DOC).

In the exported file I have the following:

[image]

I want to remove the pager containing the only chapter title (مراجع). except this, all thing are ok.

Comment: `\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}`? Really impossible to say given the dearth of information about what you are doing and what you want to do. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Note that the bibliography is unnumbered by default, so if yours is not, you must have told LaTeX you want it to be numbered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your references file, remove the line

```
\chapter*{مراجع}%\markboth{مراجع}{مراجع}‎
```

and the problem is gone.

Note that the `thebibliography` environment automatically inserts a sectioning heading, so the above line is not needed.

Note also that you are `\include`ing it, so a `\clearpage` is issued before that and `\addcontentsline` will refer to the correct page.